# Shell Script to copy from one file to another file

Tags: shell

Suppose there is a file.txt in which somewhere in between **"Start from here"** line is written.So my requirement is to copy the entire text from this line to the EOF in another file  using **shell script**.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

write_=false

while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [ $write_ == true ]; then
        echo $line
    elif [ "$line" == "Start from here" ]; then
        write_=true
    fi
done < "file.txt" > "other_file.txt"
```

files.txt

```
foo foo foo
bar bar bar
Start from here
This should be
in the file
and not anything else
```

Comment: I'd move `>> other_file.txt` out of the loop, to `done < file.txt >> other_file.txt`, or you open and close it for every line.

Comment: TIL bash can have more than one set of arrows at the end of the loop. I have updated the answer to include that change among a couple other edge cases. Thank you.